# How to fix Unrecognized WebSocket connection option(s) on RN app

Tags: react-native, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am using laravel-echo client on RN app.

```
     broadcaster: "socket.io",
     host: SOCKT_SERVER_URL,
     client: Socketio,
     auth: {
       headers: {
         Authorization: "Bearer " + SOCKET_SERVER_TOKEN
       }
     }
   });


   echo
     .channel("ticket-notification." + props.id)
     .listen("PrivateTicketCommentsNotification", event => {
       console.log("------->", event);
       //Handle event
     });
```

laravel server work as well for this
but while connecting echo server 
I am getting this issue

Unrecognized WebSocket connection option(s) `agent`, `perMessageDeflate`, `pfx`, `key`, `passphrase`, `cert`, `ca`, `ciphers`, `rejectUnauthorized`. Did you mean to put these under `headers`?
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/logging.js:25:23 in warn
- ... 27 more stack frames from framework internals

Thanks for your advance.

Comment: currently that is working with socket server and clients

Comment: but still yet warning. how can I fix this warning.

Comment: We are trying exactly the same thing. Have you found anything yet?

Comment: still yet. I have try with normal socketIO client. but ....

Answer (score 0):

```
let echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: "socket.io",
      host: SOCKT_SERVER_URL,
      client: socketIO,
      auth: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + SOCKET_SERVER_TOKEN
        }
      },
      timeout: 10000,
      jsonp: false,
      transports: ["websocket"],
      autoConnect: false,
      agent: "-",
      pfx: "-",
      key: "Bearer " + SOCKET_SERVER_TOKEN,
      cert: "-",
      ca: "-",
      ciphers: "-",
      rejectUnauthorized: "-",
      perMessageDeflate: "-"
    });
```

I got solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nodejs on your server just add this key to your options:

```
var socket = io(ENDPOINT, {forceNode:true})
```